# Python returning unique strings from the list

Tags: python, list

Write a function which takes a list of strings as input and returns unique values in the list.

Sample:

```
>>> unique_list(['cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'bug', 'dog', 'ant', 'dog', 'bug'])
['cat', 'dog', 'bug', 'ant']
```

My current code:

```
def unique_list(input_list):
    for word in input_list:
        if word not in input_list:
            output_list = [word]
            return output_list
    print(output_list)
```

I get this error(s):

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    unique_list(['cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'bug', 'dog', 'ant', 'dog', 'bug'])
  File "/Users/****/Desktop/University/CompSci 101/Lab Work/Lab 05/lab05_Homework.py", line 12, in unique_list
    print(output_list)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'output_list' referenced before assignment
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you know that you can use `list(set(['cat', 'dog', 'cat']))` => ['cat', 'dog']

Comment: @Jiri put that as answer

Comment: @WebOrCode This does not fully answer his question 'what am i doing wrong' ;)

Comment: The if statement is wrong. You should initialize output_list at the beginning and append instead of re-assigning and your return statement is in the wrong place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `if` statement is never `True`.

That is because you are getting `word` from the list and then checking that it is not in it. Doesn't make sense since the only way you got `word` from `input_list` is if it **was** in it. Therefore, your `output_list` never gets created and so when you try to print it, you get the error that the local variable `'output_list'` referenced before assignment.

However, I suggest an easier way to get unique elements would be to use [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html):

```
>>> print list(set(['cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'bug', 'dog', 'ant', 'dog', 'bug']))
['cat', 'dog', 'bug', 'ant']
```

Sets are "Unordered collections of unique elements" and therefore when you cast a list of repeating elements as a set, it will get the unique elements which you can then cast back to a list as I did above with `list(your_set)` to print it.

Alternatively, if this is some kind of coding practice and you want to stick to your method, just add an initialization line for `output_list` in your method as follows:

```
def unique_list(input_list):
    output_list = []
    ... #Rest of your code
```

### Clarification: Why your code doesn't work (Simplified Example)

```
>>> nums = [0,1,2,3,4]
>>> for i in nums:
...     if i not in nums:
...         print 'True'
...     else:
...         print 'False'
False
False
False
False
False
```

Comment: I've added "output_list = []" and now the function only returns the empty list instead of unique words in the list... What is the problem?

Comment: @SuccessfulFail, As I stated in the first line of my answer, there is a problem with your logic. I would suggest you look at it.

Comment: @SuccessfulFail, I'll updated my answer, just a minute.

Comment: @SuccessfulFail, Answer updated. Reduced version of what mistake you are making.

Answer (score 1):

Here are minor, but critical, changes to your code:

```
def unique_list(input_list):
    output_list = []
    for word in input_list:
        if word not in output_list:
            output_list.append(word)
    print(output_list)
    return output_list
```